# Run a large section of code in R with code (to initialize start of section and end)

Tags: r

I'm running a large section of code and don't want to repeatedly do "highlight code" + ctrl+enter approach. I know I can put the whole code into a if or loop like below.
for

```
for (all in 1 ) { the whole code section }
if (1==1){ the whole code section}
```

Is there a more "proper" way to do this? This works but feels not as what function is intended. Thanks

EDIT Update: To be more specific like a code to initialize, then a code to end

```
START CODE SECTION **ABC** FROM HERE

{the whole code section}

END CODE SECTION **ABC** HERE
```

It would be useful to be able to move the END and START codes for testing sections, without having to spend time moving code around or highlighting the parts repeatedly.

Comment: Put it into a function, and run it? (Could you maybe add more specific info on what "run a large section of code" means?)

Comment: sorry, i've updated with more specific question

Comment: Then another approach could be a "notebook"-chunk-approach using `RMarkdown`/`Quarto`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just surround it with braces, no for loop, if statement, etc needed:

```
{
  print("multiple lines of code")
  print("will run all at once.")
}
```

You could also use `local()`. This is handy when you’re creating intermediate objects that you don’t want cluttering up your global environment:

```
z <- local({
  x <- 1
  y <- 2
  x + y
})

z # 3
x # object 'x' not found
```